# Optimization for the autoRec algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, recommender-system

In its original paper, [autoRec](https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Eakmenon/papers/autorec/autorec-paper.pdf) proposes the following algorithm:

$min_{\theta} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \|r^{i} - h(r^{i}, \theta)\|^2_{\mathcal{O}} + \frac{\lambda}{2} (\|W\|_{F}^2 + \|V\|_{F}^{2})$

where $\|\cdot\|^2_{\mathcal{O}}$ means that we only consider the contribution of observed ratings, and $r^{(i)}$ is the user's rating on the $ith$ item. It is not clear to me what $\|\cdot\|_{\mathcal{O}}$ really means. Looking at how it is implemented [here](https://d2l.ai/chapter_recommender-systems/autorec.html). The final output goes through the procedure `pred * np.sign(input)`, but I am still confused as to what is the reason for doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pred * np.sign(input)` is taken to be the output of the decoder during training. This way, we get only the estimate of the ratings (inputs) that were observed, assigning $0$ to the outputs that correspond to the unobserved ratings.

This works because the inputs related to unobserved ratings are $0$ valued $\rightarrow$ `np.sign(unobserved_input)=np.sign(0)=0` as the [numpy.sign](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) documentation explains.

**But why is this done?**

This is done in order to update the weights of the decoder through backprop (ignoring regularization) **only if** the related input is an observed rating ($\neq 0$). To see this, we can have a look at how the sum of squares, $C$, would look like if we took into account both the observed and unobserved ratings:
$$C=\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \|r^{i} - h(r^{i}, \theta)\|^2$$
This means that, through backprop, each weight $w_k^i$ that connects a neuron $k$ of the hidden layer to a neuron $i$ of the output layer (which gives the prediction $h(r^{i}, \theta)$), would be updated with a quantity proportional to:
$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial w^i_k}= \frac{\partial C}{\partial h^i}\frac{\partial h^i}{\partial w^i_k} = -2(r^i-h(r^{i}, \theta))\,\,\frac{\partial h^i}{\partial w^i_k}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\propto \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (r^i-h(r^{i}, \theta))$$

In general, the rating predictions for unobserved ratings are $\neq0$, but if we impose $h(r^{i}, \theta)=0$ for the unobserved ratings ($r^i=0$) then we can see that we would get:
$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial w^i_k} \propto (r^i-h(r^{i}, \theta))=(r^i-0)= r^i=0 \,\,\,\,\,\,\Rightarrow\,\,\,\,\,\, \frac{\partial C}{\partial w^i_k}=0$$

So the gradients associated with the unobserved ratings would be masked out. Now we understand why `pred * np.sign(input)` achieves this.

So **to sum up**, `pred * np.sign(input)` is used to transform:
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \|r^{i} - h(r^{i}, \theta)\|^2 \,\,\,\,\text{ into }\,\,\,\, \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \|r^{i} - h(r^{i}, \theta)\|^2_{\mathcal{O}}$$
Where $\|\cdot\|^2_{\mathcal{O}}$ is used to remark that only the observed ratings are used in the learning process with backprop as we have seen above.

---

**Edit regarding the comments**

Although it's not directly related with the cost function, it may be worthy remarking that the weights represented in the paper by $V$ will also be masked out during backprop if they are related to unobserved inputs.

This is because the update on a weight $v_i^k$ that connects a input neuron $i$ with a hidden layer neuron $k$ is given by a quantity proportional to:
$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial v_i^k} = \delta^k\,r^i \propto r^i$$

Hence, if we have an unobserved input ($r^i=0$) then all the weights that go out from that neuron won't be updated. This also happens to the biases as their update is also proportional to $r^i$.

Finally, in order to help with the notation used in this answer, here it is an image of the network **taken from the article** [AutoRec](https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Eakmenon/papers/autorec/autorec-paper.pdf):

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this very thoroughly!!! Do they only want to control the parameters $W$ in the output layer? What about $V$?

Comment: Regarding the weights in $V$, their updates depend on all the neurons of the output layer. Hence, unless all the values of $r^i$ were $0$, the values of $\partial C/\partial v^k_i$ will be non-zero in general. However, it's true that the weights $w_k^i$ that have zero gradient will not contribute to the update on the weight $v^k_i\rightarrow$ We achieve control in $V$ in this way.

Comment: One final comment if I may. The way they describe this is a little bit misleading in my humble opinion. I think essentially $min_{\theta} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \|r^{i} - h(r^{i}, \theta)\|^2_{\mathcal{O}} + \frac{\lambda}{2} (\|W\|_{F}^2 + \|V\|_{F}^{2})$ is equivalent to $ min_{\theta} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \|r^{i} - h(r^{i}, \theta)\|^2 + \frac{\lambda}{2} (\|W\|_{F}^2 + \|V\|_{F}^{2})$ because $r^{i}$ is equal to $0$ for unobserved data, and in order to minimize we need to take $h(r^{i}, \theta) = 0$. The way they phrase it makes it look like it some sort of special gradient update rule.

Comment: Yes that's the idea behind that formula. It's just a way to formalize and explicitely state that the outputs related to unobserved ratings are not being considered during backprop.

Comment: @Adam I have just edited the bottom of the question with some more info about $V$. This info is not directly related to the cost function (it's related with the inputs of unobserved ratings being introduced as $0$'s) but I think it may be useful.

Comment: @Adam, have these answers solved your question?

Comment: Yes!! sorry that I forgot to assign the credits.

Answer (score 1):

Hi: It's been a while since I looked at recommender systems but that term is just summing the differences between the actual ratings in column $i$ of the  ratings matrix and  the predicted ratings in column $i$ of the predicted matrix.

It then does this for each column of the ratings matrix. So, it's a measure of how well the matrix is being mimiced by the algorithm (which is generating a matrix as similar as possible to the original matrix but also predicting the zero elements of the original matrix).

So, $h(r^{i},\theta)$ takes the column $i$ of the matrix and a parameter vector $\theta$ and produces a new rating for each element in the column. That new rating gets subtracted from the actual rating and squared in order to calculate an "error sum of squares", if you will. It's like the SSE in OLS and one wants to minimize that along with some other regularization factors. The || || notation is called a norm but in your case, you can think of it as just subtracting two vectors and then squaring the differences and summing them.

Comment: The norm $\| \cdot \|_{\mathcal{O}}$ they use is not the Euclidean norm, and that is what confuses me.

Comment: why do you think it's not euclidean ? because of the weird zero on the bottom of it ? When I looked at recommender systems in the past, it was always euclidean or something straightforward but I'm not sure what the zero is on the bottom of it. Apologies for not understanding your question originally. I understand now but I can't answer it !!!!!

Comment: I just read JavierTG's great answer but only quickly. It sounds like it's euclidean with some caveat that I don't have time to try and  understand right now.

Comment: @Adam: Javier TG  showed that the derivative during backprop becomes incorrect if you don't skip the zeros. The derivation is quite nice but even if the derivative wasn't effected, it's still makes sense to skip them.  One should really think of the zeros as NA's rather than zeros because there were no ratings for those elements of the matrix. So, you don't want the objective function to be calculated over elements that  are non-existent. I always wondered why they put zero in the non-predicted locations of the ratings matrix ?  Confusing for sure and thanks to Javier for the derivation.

Comment: I would guess that it's for the sake of convenience. This way, just by using ```pred * np.sign(input)``` we achieve this effect. Other techniques (which may be external to this problem) like Dropout are commonly used in a similar way, where the activations being masked out take the $0$ value. PS: thanks for the kind words

Comment: @Javier TG: You're welcome. I just wanted Adam to know that the O on the norm is really due to the fact that they don't label the original ratings correctly. Also, I should have said "not-rated" locations of the ratings matrix ?" in my second to last sentence, rather than "non-predicted". Typo or mental mistake there. I don't remember but that makes my comment confusing.